# mongod command is not working now. It was working before

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I don't know what is the issue. Why the mongod command is not working now. It was working before. It takes some errors when I write mongod. I am using win32 operation system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the error message it says "Detected unclean shutdown... mongod.lock is not empty"

This means that your mongod was not terminated gracefully - perhaps a hard kill.

In order to start your mongod process again, you'll have to delete this lock file. The path of the file from your error message should be:

```
C:\data\db\mongod.lock
```

Here is a link to the relevant documentation where they describe the process of recovering a mongod instance after it was shut down incorrectly.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/

Comment: Glad to help @AnkitParmar :) Happy coding!